# $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and nilpotency

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence

I am currently reviewing some examples of nilpotent groups.  Why isn't $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ nilpotent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that any nilpotent group is solvable. But $GL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is not solvable, because it possesses a free non-abelian subgroup, the so-called [Sanov subgroup](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sanov_subgroup_in_SL(2,Z)_is_free_of_rank_two).

Comment: wow, I'm surprised I missed that...Thanks, marking as answered!